# How do you change variable value(s) in Java based on user input in a GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am currently designing a GUI for a farm. The farm consists of three actors (Weed, Bean Plant and the Farmer). Upon running the Farm GUI, it shows the movement of the Farmer planting and removing Weed from the farm field. I have defined probabilities for the actors to ensure the field is not overpopulated.

The following are declared in the Simulator class. The probabilities are as follows:

```
    public final double FARMER_CREATION_PROB = 0.01;
    public final double BEANPLANT_CREATION_PROB = 0.01;
    public final double WEED_CREATION_PROB = 0.01;
```

I am now designing a seperate GUI which allows the variables above (and more) to be changed based on what the user inputs. For example, I have a JTextField for the Weed creation probability, if the user enters 3, then I want the FARMER_CREATION_PROB = 3;.

This is how I have created my JTextFields for the three probabilities (Declared in FarmGUI class):

```
 weedField = new JTextField ();
 beanField = new JTextField ();
 farmerField = new JTextField();
```

With my limited understanding of Java, I have tried the following:

```
public final double WEED_CREATION_PROB = weedField.getText();
```

However, it states "cannot find symbol". I'm pretty sure that my approach is not the correct way to go about it anyway.

**Question**:
How do I obtain the user input from the GUI and ensure it changes the creation probabilities to what the user has entered?

**Edit**:

First of all, thanks for the feedback.

This is the GUI I have designed (very basic)

[IMG]http://i57.tinypic.com/2j63668.png[/IMG]

**The Logic of the GUI**: The whole purpose of the Gui is to enable the user to set the values for each field. Upon clicking "Run Simulation" in the GUI above, another GUI where the simulation is run would appear on a separate frame.

**Edit 2**:

I have tried the following (based on @zaibi099 suggestion), just wondering if it is correct.

In the Simulator Class:

```
    public final double WEED_CREATION_PROB;
```

In the Farm GUI Class:

```
        run.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
           double s = Double.parseDouble(weedField.getText());
```

Comment: by using listeners maybe...

Comment: *With my limited understanding of Java, I have tried the following:* give us the code around this statement. I feel like this is declared in the wrong location, or incorrectly in general.

Comment: Actually, you should probably not make them final doubles if you're assigning them through the GUI. You should assign them through a ButtonListener.

Comment: @Compass It's not constructive to give point hints, as the entire approach *seems* wrong. Fixing some bad places will only add confusion. To name a few things done wrong (and each and every needs fixing): Shadowing instead of assigning, trying to assign to final, trying to assign a String to a double, allowing freeform text in a number field, no context to assignment. What we need is (as you said) *context for the code*, so we can correct the approach or point in the direction of the proper questions to ask, not fix the above errors one by one.

Comment: Edit the question and explain: (a) the logic of the GUI. Do the fields appear in the same frame? A different frame? At the same time? When a button is pressed? (b) the place where the GUI fields are defined vs. where the FARMER_CREATION_PROBE and the other constants are defined. I can say one thing at the moment: getting the values for `final` fields from a GUI is probably not what you want.

Comment: You should learn something about "Inversion of control" - in this case this means that when the user changes a value in the gui, the GUI Object (JTextField) initiates the change of the value in the class. This usually is done by using listeners, like the OnChange-Listener. A listener can be told what to, if some event (the changing of a value in this case) occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Mistakes you are making:

1. these both are not type compatible. `weedField.getText();` returns string and you are assigning it to double
2. You are trying to assign value to final(constant variable) so it'll not allow you to do that.constant can be assign to value first time.

Solution :
`public final double FARMER_CREATION_PROB;`

and where you want to assign do this :

```
FARMER_CREATION_PROB = weedField.getText();  // don't forget to convert the text field into double
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! Please make sure to use proper formatting in your posts in the future.

Comment: Hi @zaibi099. First of all, thank you for your answer, however I have tried your suggestion, but to no avail. I have stated: '  public final static double FARMER_CREATION_PROB = farmerField.getText();' however farmerField comes up with an error stating "cannot find symbol". I have successfully obtained each String from each JTextField and converted them into double or int variables, however, I am now left with how to assign the user input in the Jtextfields to constants.